# Do I need to consider airport transit visa for France?

Tags: france, transit-visas

I would be travelling to Santiago, Chile from New Delhi, India this weekend. I hold a valid visa for Chile only. I had booked a ticket to fly New Delhi - Paris - Santiago. I have a five hour layover at Charles de Gaulle Airport, Paris, France.

Answer (score 0):

you will be just in the transit-area.
if you don't want to leave this area, you don't need any transit-visa.

had the same question, when i was traveling from vienna to hongkong via Sheremetyevo Airport in Moscow. I just stayed in the (quite boring) transit area.

just if you have to check out your luggage and check in again (in case you booked 2 different tickets at 2 different airlines and no check-through is possible) you would need to leave the transit-area and would be in need of a transit-visa